# Much noise when reaching a certain frame

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, noise-reduction

I'm working on a project of my own, maximum detail as possible (it's to see how far I can reach details in a render optimizing the maximum possible)

To the question. I have a video right now on 1024 samples. (291 from 1440 at 56 minutes per frame) Very slow. Originally the video was 169 samples, more than enough for what I want (5 minutes). The problem came when upgrading to blender 2.78c (I think) I use the Steam version. All good until on reaching the frame 707, the render was made with a lot of noise, like if had gone from 169 samples to 32 samples. To match this loss with 169 samples I have to increase at 750 samples approx. and still see a small difference, so I started from 0 with 1024 samples where the difference is not noticeable.

I have a GTX 660, the render takes much time, for that reason I had the limit on 169 samples, is like a camera of 5Mpx (1280x720).

Soon I will buy a GTX 1060 6GB to improve the speed and memory VRAM and be able to increase the quality of the render.

I would like to know what produces this error and how to solve it. (I leave a capture of the difference between frame 706 (top) and 707 (below) render is a camera that moves linearly with blur effect at 169 samples at 1280x720P 24Fps and random noise).

EDIT 1:

**Information:**
It's a stage (racing circuit, with grandstands, sand, some fences and a car in the middle). Specifically, this video builds the stage using the BUILD tool of blender. The only thing that happens at that point is the BUILD in (car and grandtands) the car goes from beginning to end of the video, the grandstands start at frame 700 and ends at 1200. The rest is built (or should be already built ). (Uses 1.7 Millions of Vertex, 1.5GB of VRAM + 2.6GB of RAM, Blur 0.5, Full GI, 1280x720 at 169 Samples Path-Traking)

In previous projects doesn't increase the amount of noise (backups that don't  have the BUILD tool). It looks like 144 samples. (Little more noise), I suppose it's because it has fewer objects and optimization than the last save.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Much noise after frame 707]

EDIT 2:

**Solved:** Thanks to **Duarte Farrajota Ramos**
The problem is Path Tracing. Changing to Branched Path Tracing problem is solved.

[image: Frame 750 Path Tracing vs Branched Path Tracing]

PS: My English is not very good, sorry.

Comment: "*I would like to know what produces this error and how to solve it*" We would too, since it might even be caused by a bug, but you don't give us any relevant info or any details about your scene or what exactly happens at frame 707 that might cause this noise, so we can't really help you much until you edit your question and provide relevant details instead of what computer you will buy.

Comment: You're right. Sorry.

I should have done more testing. In previous copies it doesn't. I updated the post.

Comment: By "build tool" I am assuming you mean the *Build Modifier*? Are there any additional lamps in your scene, specifically any that might get occluded by the changing geometry?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the build modifier.
I delete all the lights (lamps) in the scene. On the other hand there are emission materials but with an intensity of 0 all the time. The only material emission working is the sun and sky which is a node to simulate real sunlight with clouds, but the intensity doesn't change at any time. Maybe it's because of the blur? I understand by tutorials that it can produce a lot of noise in certain cases.

Comment: Those emission materials might be to blame. Cycles basically starts searching for new light sources and scatters all available rendering samples. If they have 0 intensity remove them or try *Branched Path Tracing* in the *Integrator* under the *Rendering Settings*

Comment: Really? Two weeks lost searching and in the end was the Path Tracing. Thanks Duarte, of course, I put Path tracing to reduce the render time since I saw that the result was the same and it saved about 3 minutes of rendering, but I had the lights (material of emission) in the scene, when putting the build modifier The lights disappeared and for that reason there was not so much noise, when arriving at the frame 707 that is when the first emission appears and is when much noise appears in the render, thank you very much !. I edit the post to see the difference.